# Adding monotouch.Dialog as part of uiviewcontroller in monotouch iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I want to create a page like this:

[image]

My idea for bottom place is using monotouhc.Dialog by `viewElement`. But the question is this:

Is using monotouch for this the best way? or using `tableview` with `datasource` is better?
And if we should use `monotouch.dialog` how we can add this as a part of a `viewcontroller`?

Comment: This looks more like a custom View to me.  I don't know that you would really get a lot out of using UITableView or MT.Dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it either way.

I would personally create a set of custom elements: one for rendering the image, one for rendering the first bit of information, one for the second bit of information.

Then I would create the UI like this:

```
new RootElement ("House"){
    new Section (){
        new HouseImageViewElement (house_id),
    },
    new Section () {
        new OverviewElement (house_id);
    },
    new Section () {
        new DetailedElement (house_id);
    }
```

In turn those elements should be built on top of reusable UIViews (see my blog post on patterns for UITableViewCells: http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Jan-18.html)

Which has the advantage that you can later use those elements elsewhere (for example to display houses in a list).   It also lets you split the management of the layout in different parts of the code.

But you can also create an entire view that does that, and then host the view with a UIViewElement in MonoTouch.Dialog, or use it manually in a UITableView, or just display it manually.